# how to disable double click in mobile page?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Double click disable code working fine for web but not for mobile.

Any one have any solution for this? thanks in advance. below is my reference code.

I want to disable the double click for mobile page where user clicking twice on submit button.

```
$(document).on('click', '#data1', function() {
   document.form1.action="";
   document.form1.submit();
   $(this).click(function () {
     return false;
   });
}
```

Comment: Can you post any code?

Comment: have posted some of my code for reference.

Comment: easier option, disable button on first click, enable it after a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try HTML:

```
 <form data-ajax="false"></form>
```

and JS:

```
 $("[your_form"].on("submit", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   // your foo here

   return false;
 });
```